# Checking the scope of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a method that checks an array against index and returns true if the index is within the scope of the array.

My code is

```
public class Q1F {
    boolean isValidIndex(int[] questionArray,int questionIndex){
        return indexOfquestionArray(questionIndex);
    }
}
```

Help? I dont know how to make it work

Comment: By the index being within the scope of the array you mean if the index is between 0 and the length of the array or something similar?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean

Comment: Well, I already gave you half of the solution. You only need to write a piece of code that explicitly validates this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza do not worry other people took care of it lol

Comment: @KickButtowski sadly, yes...

Answer (score 2):

A valid array index is between `0` and `array.length - 1`. You don't need an instance of your class so I would make the method `static` and you should check that the array isn't `null` and that could be done with something like,

```
static boolean isValidIndex(int[] array, int index) {
    return array != null && index >= 0 && index < array.length;
}
```